# Why isn't this onchange event triggering?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to detect when a `<select>` element that was dynamically added has had its option changed. However, it does not trigger when I change it.

The code:

```
var diP = document.createElement("select");


diP.add(option);
diP.add(option2);

diP.addEventListener("change", alert("Test"));

div2.appendChild(diP);
```

The code does not alert anything when I change the option.

Comment: it will never work as it is because all your code is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass callback as argument to event listener, among with event type.

```
diP.addEventListener("change", () => alert("Test"));
```

Also, please check if you've selected HTML element `div2` correctly.

HTML:

```
<div class="div2"> ... </div>
```

JS:

```
const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2')
```

Answer (score 0):

For addEventListener's, you need to pass the name of the function, not call the function. Or you can pass it an anonymous function.

```
function funcName(){

}

diP.addEventListener("change", funcName);
```

or

```
diP.addEventListener("change", function(){
   console.log(this.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that instead you see one alert when your script executes for the first time because instead of passing a function to the `addEventListener` you  call it.

In order to have alert shown when input changes, you need to pass a function which runs in response to the `change` event. So your code should look like this:

```
....
diP.addEventListener("change", () => alert("Test"));
...
```

This way you say "run a function which will make an alert each time input changes".